# Ionic 4: 2 column grid list virtual scroll issue

Tags: ionic4

I am trying to do virtual scrolling on ionic 4 to display two column list, below piece of code without virtual scroll makes 2 column grid. But with virtual scrolling it's displaying only one. I don't know what I am doing wrong, any help will be appreciated.

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-virtual-scroll [items]="currentProducts">
       <ion-col size="6" size-sm="4" size-lg="3" no-padding *virtualItem="let product">
       <ion-card class="product" (click)="productSelected(product)">
         <ion-card-content>
           <div class="product">
               <ion-img [src]="product.thumbnails[0]" alt="brandLogo"></ion-img>
               <div class="product-text">
                   <h3 text-center>{{product.brand.name}}</h3>
                   <h5 text-center>{{product.name}}</h5>
                   <p text-center>{{product.itemNumber}}</p>
                   <h6 text-center>${{product.retailPrice}}</h6>
               </div>
           </div>
         </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-virtual-scroll>
</ion-row>
```

This piece of code is without virtual scrolling, which displays two column grid list.

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col size="6" size-sm="4" size-lg="3" no-padding *ngFor="let product of currentProducts">
       <ion-card class="product" (click)="productSelected(product)">
          <ion-card-content>
             <div class="product">
                <img src="{{product.thumbnails[0]}}" alt="brandLogo">
                <div class="product-text">
                    <h3 text-center>{{product.brand.name}}</h3>
                    <h5 text-center>{{product.name}}</h5>
                    <p text-center>{{product.itemNumber}}</p>
                    <h6 text-center>${{product.retailPrice}}</h6>
                </div>
             </div>
           </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried to put the ion-virtual-scroll outside the ion-grid like this example: http://embed.plnkr.co/S0IiIu/ but it throws an error. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: Same problem for me, I see there is a git issue here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/646. try to add comments there, maybe they will do something about this

Answer (score 0):

To support two column view inside virtual scroll make each of the virtual scroll item to be a pair of our original items and show them one after another in the single row. For example,

```
<ion-virtual-scroll [items]="pairs">
  <div class="row" *virtualItem="let pair">
    <div class="column">
     {{ pair[0] }}
    </div>
    <div class="column">
     {{ pair[1] }}
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-virtual-scroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

A trick to support dynamic multi columns in ionic virtual scroll.
you can see how to do it here:

https://dev.to/timsar2/how-ionic-virtual-scroll-support-dynamic-multiple-columns-and-infinity-scroll-38jm

just make a list as index of datasource and then pass it with a pipe to virtual list items.

Then use ngfor to create columns in a row.

Try to resize screen in stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-by5rkf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html